# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'par' referenced before assignment:

Tags: django, nlp, huggingface-transformers, qas

I want to get the `context`  data into a `par` variable to be processed into the pipeline `context=par`. but got this error, how can i fix this ?

```
def index(request):
    qas_form = QasForms()
    post_form = MyForm(request.POST)
    db_context = Context.objects.filter(category=post_form)

    for con in db_context :
        par= con.context

    context = {
        'heading' : 'Question Answering',
        'data_form' :qas_form,
        'form' : post_form,
        'Cont' : db_context,
    }

    model_name = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('./save_model', from_tf=True)
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('./save_model')
    nlp = pipeline('question-answering', model=model_name, tokenizer=tokenizer)
        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        question = request.POST['question']
        par = hasil
        result = nlp(question=question, context=par)
        context['question'] = question
        context['answer'] = result['answer']
    return render(request,'qas/index.html',context)
```

I am trying to get a solution to this problem

Comment: What is `hasil`?

Comment: I'm sorry that line shouldn't be there

Comment: In that case what would be the value of `par` if `db_context` is empty?

Comment: it should contain a paragraph of text from the database

Comment: @Fortisen The point is that there is no paragraph of text from the database when `db_context` is empty. You should consider initializing `par` with a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize **`par`** variable as None at before for loop then you can assign value like **`par = con.context`**

```py
qas_form = QasForms()
post_form = MyForm(request.POST)
db_context = Context.objects.filter(category=post_form)
par = None # here need to initialize  
for con in db_context :
    par= con.context
```